# При обновление ветки ошибка

Tags: git

Здравствуйте, делаю git status, вижу такое [image]

Далее делаю git push origin/branch_name

[image]

Не могу понять, раньше всегда так получалось. Не подскажете как решать это?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы хотите обновить remote ветку MARAT-DOLOTOV используя локальную ветку BOSS-STYLE? Тогда указывайте обе ветки явно:

```
git push origin BOSS-STYLE:MARAT-DOLOTOV
```

Comment: Спасибо, огромное))